# How to escape characters in a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

When I use the following code I've got an error:

```
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("/Date\(\d+\)/");
```

The error is :

`invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

I have also tried to change the value in the brackets to`('/Date\(\d+\)/')`; without any success.

How can i avoid this error?

Comment: You might need to escape the "\"s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to double-escape your `\` character, like this: `\\`.

Otherwise your `String` is interpreted as if you were trying to escape `(`.

Same with the other round bracket and the d.

In fact it seems you are trying to initialize a `Pattern` here, while `pattern.matcher` references a text you want your `Pattern` to match.

Finally, note that in a `Pattern`, escaped characters require a double escape, as such:

```
\\(\\d+\\)
```

Also, as Rohit says, `Pattern`s in Java do not need to be surrounded by forward slashes (`/`).

In fact if you initialize a `Pattern` like that, it will interpret your `Pattern` as starting and ending with literal forward slashes.

Here's a small example of what you probably want to do:

```
// your input text
String myText = "Date(123)";
// your Pattern initialization
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Date\\(\\d+\\)");
// your matcher initialization
Matcher m = p.matcher(myText);
// printing the output of the match...
System.out.println(m.find());
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: And also, in Java you don't need to give any delimiter in regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is correct *by itself*, but in Java, the backslash character itself needs to be escaped.

Thus, this regex:

```
/Date\(\d+\)/
```

Must turn into this:

```
/Date\\(\\d+\\)/
```

One backslash is for escaping the parenthesis or `d`. The other one is for escaping the backslash itself.

The error message you are getting arises because Java thinks you're trying to use `\(` as a single escape character, like `\n`, or any of the other examples. However, `\(` is not a valid escape sequence, and so Java complains.

---

In addition, the logic of your code is probably incorrect. The argument to `matcher` should be the text to search (for example, "/Date(234)/Date(6578)/"), whereas the variable `pattern` should contain the pattern itself. Try this:

```
String textToMatch = "/Date(234)/Date(6578)/";
Pattern pattern = pattern.compile("/Date\\(\\d+\\)/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textToMatch);
```

---

Finally, the regex character class `\d` means "one single digit." If you are trying to refer to the literal phrase `\\d`, you would have to use `\\\\d` to escape this. However, in that case, your regex would be a constant, and you could use `textToMatch.indexOf` and `textToMatch.contains` more easily.

Comment: Regex in Java don't need any delimiter. And you need to escape `\\d+` too.

Comment: `\d` means "a single digit" in regex. I'm interpreting the code to be a logic error; see my edit.

Comment: I have tried your code like pattern.matcher("/Date\\(\d+\\)/"); and i got the same error...

Comment: @John Please read the whole post. That code was copy-pasted from *your* post; the fix is two lines below it.

Comment: Now I did and tried your code as follows and now I got the error in the compile brackets,please see that our input is little bit diffrent   String textToMatch = "/Date(1224043200000)/";
  Pattern pattern = pattern.compile("/Date\\(\d+\\)/");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textToMatch);

Comment: The regex you are using is wrong. Try the one in the code block: `"/Date\\(\\d+\\)/"`.

Answer (score 0):

To escape regex in java, you can also use `Pattern.quote()`